# installing ubuntu and starting windows isn't in boot option

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive

I didn't installing ubuntu alongside my windows7.

I have windows7 installed in my ssd and ubuntu in another.
Right before I install ubuntu, I unplugged all my other hdd.  1st because it the ubuntu installation somehow didn't detect the hdd I want to install onto and 2nd because in that way I would be I didn't choose the wrong hdd to install ubuntu onto.

After ubuntu install is completed and running, I plugged my windows7 hdd and other storage hdd back.

But somehow when I restart my pc, it didn't even ask which os to use it just directly goes into ubuntu.  I used F12 to have the option to select device to boot up with and I can clearly see my windows7 ssh and of course by clicking it, windows7 boots up properly.

I went into my bios and check my boot priority and options.  There are only two boot options and the first is my ubuntu hdd and second is my optic drive.  When I try to change the boot option, those two are the only options I can choose from.  I cannot choose from any other hdd.

Can someone give me a hand?
Not sure if this is the place to post my question but this happened after ubuntu installation.

Thanks in advance people.

Comment: Did you unplug the drive with the Windows 7 installation ? If so, the installer cannot detect the Windows 7 install, and won't set up the dual boot options which would let you choose which OS to start at boot. In this case, to fix this, boot into your Ubuntu install, and run `sudo update-grub`, with the Windows 7 drive connected.

Comment: @JonasCz I get what you mean but I just run the command you gave me in ubuntu but sitll no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for grub loader, please enter the following command in ubuntu-

```
sudo update-grub
```

After executing the above commands, reboot and check if the grub loader appears.
I had faced similar issue where I did not get the option to install ubuntu alongside windows and Ubuntu was loaded automatically. After executing the above mentioned command, I got the grub loader where I could choose the OS to load.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I did run that command but another thing is, I installed ubuntu in a different hdd though.  I ran the command and rebooted, still the same.  Just boot to ubuntu right away instead of letting me choose os to boot

Comment: I realized why now and thanks this does help.
But is there a way to organize the boot options for the menu? Ubuntu is always first and windows is always last.  Is there a way to put windows on top?

Comment: You are welcome. Grub customizer could be used to edit grub.

Comment: so the grub customizer is the answer `aaaltnate` provided? I just use the commands he gave? `repository, update then install?`

Comment: Yeah. It is a graphical user interface. You may need to execute the commands that aaaltnate mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, run `sudo update-grub`. Then, add the `grub-customizer` PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

After it's installed, check the first and second tabs if there's anything hidden (especially grub-hidden-timeout).
After tinkering VERY CAREFULLY, save and reboot.